# client number in a java multithread server

Tags: java, multithreading

I use two classes in my server

### Myserver.java

```
private ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);        

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  server = new MyServer();
  server.runServer();
}

private void runServer() {        
  int serverPort = 8071;
  try {
    System.out.println("Starting Server");
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(serverPort); 

    while(true) {
      System.out.println("Waiting for request");
      try {
        Socket s = serverSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("Processing request");
        executorService.submit(new ServiceRequest(s));
      } catch(IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("Error accepting connection");
        ioe.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }catch(IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Error starting Server on "+serverPort);
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

and

### ServiceRequest.java

```
private Socket socket;
BufferedReader input = null;

public ServiceRequest(Socket connection) {
  this.socket = connection;
}

public void run() {

  try {
    //input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));


    DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

    System.out.println("Client "+ clientID +"Connected");
```

I want to get the number of each Client in `run()` ( I want to get a result in the last line of the code ). How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a new service request, you can keep a global counter for IDs... but it's very important to use [`AtomicLong`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html), not a regular `int` or `long`, if you want to keep unique ids.

```
private static AtomicLong idCounter = new AtomicLong();
private long clientId = idCounter.incrementAndGet();
```

This is how you can create `clientId`s in a threadsafe way, as the instance variable `clientId` will create a new value atomically each time a `ServiceRequest` is generated.

Answer (score 0):

Each time run() is called it should be on a new object of type `ServiceRequest`. You can assign each of these a unique clientID when they are instantiated.

This might not work in java, but it's easy to implement similar functionality. In `ServiceRequest` add these lines:

```
private static int counter = 0;
protected int clientID = counter++;
```

This means each time a `ServiceRequest` is created, it's member variable clientID is one larger than the previous. It's not thread-safe but I think java has something called `volatile` that might work.